# Undesired output when left_join() ing time stamped dataframes in R

Tags: r, left-join

I can't understand why my code is providing an undesired ouput since I've tried this in the past with similar datasets and good results.

Below are the two dataframes I would like to `left_join()`:

```
> head(datagps)
   Date & Time [Local]  Latitude Longitude            DateTime   meters
1:    06/11/2018 08:44 -2.434986  34.85387 2018-11-06 08:44:00 1.920190
2:    06/11/2018 08:48 -2.434993  34.85386 2018-11-06 08:48:00 3.543173
3:    06/11/2018 08:52 -2.435014  34.85388 2018-11-06 08:52:00 1.002979
4:    06/11/2018 08:56 -2.435011  34.85389 2018-11-06 08:56:00 3.788024
5:    06/11/2018 09:00 -2.434986  34.85387 2018-11-06 09:00:00 1.262584
6:    06/11/2018 09:04 -2.434994  34.85386 2018-11-06 09:04:00 3.012679
> head(datasensorraw)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  TimeGroup               x     y     z
  <dttm>              <int> <int> <dbl>
1 2000-01-01 00:04:00     0     0   0  
2 2000-01-01 00:08:00     1     0   1  
3 2000-01-01 00:12:00     0     0   0  
4 2000-01-01 00:20:00     0     0   0  
5 2000-01-01 00:24:00     0     0   0  
6 2018-06-09 05:04:00     4    14  14.6
```

And below is my code. There are no `Errors`, but for some reason I get `NA`'s under `x`, `y` and `z`. This should not happen since there are registered values in the `datasensorraw` dataframe for those time stamps:

```
> library(dplyr)
> dataresults<-datagps %>% 
+   mutate(`Date & Time [Local]` = as.POSIXct(`Date & Time [Local]`, 
+                                             format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")) %>%
+   left_join(datasensorraw, by = c("Date & Time [Local]" = "TimeGroup"))
> #Left join the data frames
> head(dataresults)
  Date & Time [Local]  Latitude Longitude            DateTime   meters  x  y  z
1 2018-11-06 07:44:00 -2.434986  34.85387 2018-11-06 08:44:00 1.920190 NA NA NA
2 2018-11-06 07:48:00 -2.434993  34.85386 2018-11-06 08:48:00 3.543173 NA NA NA
3 2018-11-06 07:52:00 -2.435014  34.85388 2018-11-06 08:52:00 1.002979 NA NA NA
4 2018-11-06 07:56:00 -2.435011  34.85389 2018-11-06 08:56:00 3.788024 NA NA NA
5 2018-11-06 08:00:00 -2.434986  34.85387 2018-11-06 09:00:00 1.262584 NA NA NA
6 2018-11-06 08:04:00 -2.434994  34.85386 2018-11-06 09:04:00 3.012679 NA NA NA
```

I can also upload a small `dput()` sample of [`datagps`](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lNo8d5OoVFnd_Nlq0DJxKpF9Hl7fuaii) and [`datasensorraw`](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xafcY9Y9CAyVF7IhU3qyQj_6eB4za-WE).

I am learning R so I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong. I shouldn't get `NA`s under those columns as you can see on the `dput()` samples provided. Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a mixup on your date format. Try to switch `format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"` to `format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"` or switch it to d/m/y in your other dataset.

```
dataresults<- datagps_sample %>% 
  mutate(`Date & Time [Local]` = as.POSIXct(`Date & Time [Local]`, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")) %>%
  left_join(datasensorraw_sample, by = c("Date & Time [Local]" = "TimeGroup"))

> head(dataresults)

  Date & Time [Local]  Latitude Longitude            DateTime   meters   x   y         z
1 2018-06-11 12:44:00 -2.434986  34.85387 2018-11-06 08:44:00 1.920190  17  12  21.59363
2 2018-06-11 12:48:00 -2.434993  34.85386 2018-11-06 08:48:00 3.543173   6   0   6.00000
3 2018-06-11 12:52:00 -2.435014  34.85388 2018-11-06 08:52:00 1.002979  47  25  53.24351
4 2018-06-11 12:56:00 -2.435011  34.85389 2018-11-06 08:56:00 3.788024   0   0   0.00000
5 2018-06-11 13:00:00 -2.434986  34.85387 2018-11-06 09:00:00 1.262584  48  53  72.23108
6 2018-06-11 13:04:00 -2.434994  34.85386 2018-11-06 09:04:00 3.012679 139 113 179.24589
```

EDIT: basically, `left_join` was not finding any matches and it was returning the rows from your original dataframe but with the new columns as `NA`. If you format your column before left joining you could check if there are common id's with something simple like `datagps$Date & Time [Local]` %in% `datasensorraw$TimeGroup`.